# Didactic / simplistic operating system for mobile phones for learning purpose

Tags: android, mobile, operating-system

Basically, I want to a mobile OS, that can be used to learn about the creation of mobile operating systems. I'd prefer one thats based on Android.

Something like [Minix](http://www.minix3.org/) for desktop: A clean and small OS perfect to use in didact's examples and things like that.
I know that I can use any linux/unix version (even Minix) and put it in a mobile device, but I believe that mobile devices has some specificities that needs special treatment and it will be good to know a specific system to deal with this.

I'm trying to avoid [Cyanogen](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) or systems with some "commercial purpose" (huge systems with many users and many specifics) .

Comment: Not sure about what you're really looking for to do with it, but as you mention *CyanogenMod* and giving "commercial" as only reason against it (you're not confusing this with [Cyanogen OS](https://cyngn.com/cyanogen-os), do you? The former is community, the latter commercial), you might be interested in [Replicant](http://www.replicant.us/) – which is completely open source.

Comment: I want to use a Android Distribution to start learning about the development of mobile OS and I believe that a distribution created for didactic purposes maybe could be a good option. I used "commercial" in a wrong way for CyanogenMod, but I just don't believe that CyanogenMod can be a good start point. I'll see this Replicant. Thx.

Comment: James, with Android there's no such thing as a "distribution" (which you might have taken from Linux). There are different custom ROMs, but they are always device-specific.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using distribution in the same way that I use for Linux. So, what's a good start point to learn about development of mobile OS?

Comment: Don't know, I'm not a dev. And this site is not the right place to ask for that (and no, Android.SE neither). Pointer, on our sister-site: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: @James Just go through this  - http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programmers/I-want-to-learn-how-to-make-Android-ROM-for-a-device-from-scratch-using-AOSP-code-I-want-to-learn-everything-From-where-should-I-learn-What-should-I-learn

Comment: @James I reworded your question to better fit the needs you expressed here in the comments. Please, do have a look if I got it right. I'd recommend Open Moko but haven't looked at its code in ages.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Thank you for editing. I could not have said it better